# Using Grub to select boot drive?

Tags: boot, grub

I have a working system which boots into Lubuntu.
I then add an old hard drive, which happens to have Ubuntu on it.

BIOS boot order is: 1 - floppy 2 - DVD 3 - Lubuntu HDD

However, the system boots into Ubuntu on the newly added drive !

Can I use Grub commands to boot from the correct Lubuntu disk ?

Comment: Why does your BIOS boot order not include the new disk? Is BIOS not recognizing it? If so, GRUB will not be able to recognize it either! Showing the Ubuntu bootscreen image is NOT "booting into Ubuntu"!

Comment: I don't want to boot from the added drive. It just happened to have Ubuntu on it, and to my surprise booting started from that drive and not the existing drive with Lubuntu. If I disconnect the added drive all is well and Lubuntu boots up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, the system boots into Ubuntu on the newly added drive !

It only means this new HDD comes up first. Of course, it also means that it has a boot sector, and a fully functional grub which knows nothing of the other disk.

Grub has no qualms with a multiple HDD system. Just update it, and it will find there are multiple disks, with multiple OSs. It will then correct the MBR to pint to the grub of the system from which you are running the update.

Then, if nothing has been corrupted, at the next reboot it will allow you to choose between multiple OSs. If this does not work, use [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair), a program you can install on a live Ubuntu distro, and will fix all of your problems, under most (though not all) circumstances. If this does not work, post the output from Boot Repair onto the Ubuntu forum, where the author of Boot Repair is kind enough to answer queries.

Comment: Thanks for explaining what's going on ! The problem is that the added Ubuntu drive does not fully boot. It first displays the Grub option , press Esc to enter Grub, then the Ubuntu logo with progressbar, then the screen goes black and is unusable.

Comment: Would it be possible, if I enter into Grub commandline, to point to the Lubuntu disk instead ?

Comment: Easiest thing is to use a Ubuntu live to fix things. Either use Boot Repair like I said above, or you may read this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/32135/stuck-on-grub-command-line